# Modern UI Sitemap in 2017R2

Tags: acumatica

I have added Acumatica GI screen as Menu Title and also as a Menu Item, to do this, first, I have unchecked Entry Screen checkbox for that GI and also changed sitemap location from hidden to help. By doing this i could able to add GI screen as both Title item and Menu item, but when i publish any package the newly added Title and Menu are getting cleared. Could anyone please suggest me some solution for this.

Comment: Have you reloaded from database sitemap in your customization after addition of the menus and before publishing the project?

Comment: Thank you, Samvel, yes if we reload sitemap from the database it is not getting cleared, but do we need to do this everytime if we change something before publishing the package.

Comment: Yes, you need to reload sitemap if you have changed anything in the Modern UI

Comment: Thank you very much Samvel.